# Exploding an array that may only have one value

Tags: php, variables, explode

I am not sure if this is doable or if its a bigger problem with in my code but I have a webpage where a user selects some values from a infinite amount. So for example there select a1 and b2 from my form.

The form then combines them so they become like this:
a1**b1 or a1**b1**d1**e1 as another example. I will then split these values up using an explode function. here is an fulll example

```
$v1 = a1**b1
$v2 = explode("**", $v1);
```

Now if the user only select one value, the explode doesnt seem to work as I dont get a value for $v2. EG

```
$v1 = a1
$v2 = explode("**", $v1);
```

Is there a way that I can get this to work? Im not sure why I don't even get a value coming out in the second example, just want to knwo if its a limitation with explode or wheter it may be something else.

Thank in advance for an help or guidance.

Ian

Comment: do you want `$v2` to always equal an array, even if there is only one result?

Comment: The explode will still work, it'll simply return an array with a single element - https://3v4l.org/HGlVB

Comment: Not true. Explode will return an empty array set...

Comment: Do I get this right, that you get that data from a client side form and want to convert it to an array to work with it on the server side? _Why?_ Simply hand it over as an array and all is good...

Comment: @Chris - only if $v1 is actually empty.... if it contains any value, then it will be a single array element containing that value

Comment: Hi @Chris, yeah I guess i need it to return an array. Basically my code after this bit refers to $v2[0], $v2[1] and so on for however many things get exploded if that makes sense

Comment: Gotcha. The docs state it will return an empty array if the delimiter is not found...

Comment: why don't you just use square brackets `[]` on your `select`'s `name` attribute like `name="inputname[]"`? it will produce array and you no more need to `explode()` the submitted data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, not sure what the actual issue here is...

First:

```
<?php
var_dump(explode('**','A'));
```

This clearly shows that the `explode()` call works as expected, the output is:

```
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  string(1) "A"
}
```

Second:

If I get that right, then you get that data from a client side form where you invest effort into creating a string and then want to convert that into an array on the server side to work with it? *Why?* Simply hand it over as an array and all is good:

You can simply use a notation like `myvalue[]` on the client side and the form submission will result in an array `$_POST['myvalue']` getting prepared on the server side you can use like any other array without the need to explode something first.

For `ajax` requests this is even easier, since you then will typically use `JSON` as transport format in your `POST` requests which supports arrays natively.